# htaccess redirect dynamic old file to new File url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

with the last update I had to change site folder and now old urls need to be redirected to the new path.. old was:

```
www.siteexamplename.com/store/index.php?product=240
```

new is:

```
www.siteexamplename.com/shop/index.php?product=240
```

how to redirect via .htaccess to the new path.. just to rename store to shop - the rest is the same..
thanks

Comment: what is you current .htaccess

Comment: in the current .htaccess I have no redirection included

Comment: #AddType application/x-httpd-php53 .php
#AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the root directory of your Website you need to create .htaccess file with next code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ /shop/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use rewrite rule-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oldDirectory/([a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)$ /newDirectory/$1 [R=301,L]
```